# How to basic search Elasticsearch via NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elk

I'm very new to NEST and Elasticsearch but at my workplace they asked me to produce a wpf client to search and retrieve documents from elasticsearch.

This is an example of what is stored in Elastic

```
{
    "_index" : "testing_devices",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "0o6ZeX8BRPRTU2ODedUM",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "timestamp_Local" : "2022-03-11T16:29:34.5763990+01:00",
      "event" : "TestLog",
      "log" : {
        "Guid" : "d8bb9004-7cb1-4594-8c93-80135a8b736c",
        "SerialNumber" : "",
        "RecordType" : 0,
        "Operatore" : "Alessandro",
        "Name" : "03) Configurazione integrato USB FTDI",
        "Result" : 0,
        "StartDate" : "2022-03-11T16:14:42.3746145+01:00",
        "EndDate" : "2022-03-11T16:14:43.6001675+01:00"
      }
    }
  }
```

**POCO**

```
public class Log
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public int RecordType { get; set; }
    public string Operatore { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

now my task is to search a document by Guid and so this is what i wrote in my client application just to test:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ElasticClient? client = new ElasticClient();
    ConnectionSettings? settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("https://elk.xyz.to:9200")).DefaultMappingFor<Log>(i=>i.IndexName("testing_devices"))
        .DefaultIndex("testing_devices")
        .ApiKeyAuthentication("xxx", "yyy");

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        var result = client.Search<Log>(s => s.Index("testing_devices").Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Guid).Query("d8bb9004-7cb1-4594-8c93-80135a8b736c"))));
    }
}
```

but no results are coming out of my query,it clearly say zero hits, as I already read a lot, without being able to produce any significant steps in order to achieve my goals, please can someone point me to the right direction?

EDIT:
I'm adding the INDEX Definition for further investigations:

[INDEX DEFINITION PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/fdnWUYrp)

Comment: your field `Guid` is inside `log`. so you need to use field name as `log.Guid`. can you try  `(f => f.log.Guid.keyword)` insted of `(f => f.Guid)`

Comment: @SagarPatel thanks...do I have to modify my POCO?

Comment: i dont have expertise in C# but you can tryout to give directly field name.

Comment: `m.Field(f => f.Guid.Suffix("keyword")` should work. Nest has a Suffix Extension method for that.

Comment: @Ralf it will not work because field is inside `log` object so he need to use `log.Guid` as field name.

Comment: Lets @FabioEnne check it. In the NEST syntax f is already of Type Log (has been given as generic parameter to the search call). And Log does not have a log Property. So don't think its needed.

Comment: @SagarPatel you use the naming on the ElasticSearch side. Nest uses the .Net type system here so it only surfaces that type. The actual name used in Elasticsearch is an internal magic of Nest it does not surface. Thats why the, at first sight, weird Suffix method is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately all of this solutions leads to empty Hits or records/documents..

Comment: Maybe showing your index definition gives some insights. Presumably a GET on  
`https://elk.xyz.to:9200/testing_devices` should deliver that.

Comment: @Ralf Edited the question to include a PasteBin of the index Definitions

Answer (score 0):

Your field `Guid` is inside `log` field. So you will be not able to execute query directly on `Guid` field and you need to use field name as `log.Guid`.

Below is sample query of Elasticsearch:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "log.Guid.keyword": "d8bb9004-7cb1-4594-8c93-80135a8b736c"
    }
  }
}
```

You can check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html#unstructured-search) for .net referance and as mentioned you need use below code.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        var result = client.Search<Log>(s => s.Index("testing_devices").Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.log.Guid.keyword).Query("d8bb9004-7cb1-4594-8c93-80135a8b736c"))));
    }
```

**Note:** If you have defined your field as `text` and `keyword` both type (or using default mapping) then you can use `log.Guid.keyword` for exact match else you need to use `log.Guid` but it will not search for exact match as it is `text` type of field.

Comment: unfortunately this still produce and empty Hits, records, and documents..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = _client.Search<Log>(s => s.Index("testing_devices").Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field("log.Guid").Query("d8bb9004-7cb1-4594-8c93-80135a8b736c"))));
```

This is returning me one hit.
You actually need to search log.Guid or log.Guid.keyword.

You can actually check the json query generated in the result object when you debug.
Look for "DebugInformation"  and see json request you are sending and it's response.[image]

**UPDATE**

The reason you are not able to get any values in the document list in the results is because

Firstly, you need to use TestingDevices class as TDocument when you are searching because of your document structure.

```
public class TestingDevices
{
    public Log log { get; set; }
}
```

And then use the following:

```
var result = _client.Search<TestingDevices>(s => s.Index("testing_devices").Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field("log.Guid").Query("d8bb9004-7cb1-4594-8c93-80135a8b736c"))));
```

Secondly, the NEST library converts your fields in the class to camel case. So when you have "Guid" in the Log class, NEST will convert it to "guid" when creating the search query, which will not be present in the index. Same goes for all the other fields as well.

Either make sure all your fields are camel cased in the index(if they are pascal case in your c# class)or use the following when creating Elastic client.

```
connectionString.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(prop => prop);
_client = new ElasticClient(connectionString);
```

When I did the above two changes, I got documents in the result set.

One more thing you can check is the data type of fields in the C# class and the index field types.

Comment: Thank you, yes I see some hits as well, but inside result there are hits and documents but the fields are all nulls...